# Detect duplicated header in HTTP::Response

Tags: perl, http-headers

I have a problem with a **HTTP::Response** Perl object from a remote server that sometimes returns the HTTP response with duplicated 'Content-Length' headers.

When this occurs, if the content-length value is '43215', when I read the header value with:

```
print ($response->header('Content-length'));
```

the result is:

```
4321543215
```

How can I detect if the header is duplicated and access to the real value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the fine manual for `HTTP::Headers`:

> A multi-valued field will be returned as separate values in list context and will be
>   concatenated with "," as separator in scalar context.

and this is list context:

```
print ($response->header('Content-length'))
```

So, `$response->header()` is returning both `Content-length` headers as a list and the result is, essentially:

```
print join('', 43215, 43215)
```

You can either use kork's `$response->content_length()` approach or grab all the `Content-length` headers in an array and use the first one as the length:

```
my @lengths = $response->header('Content-length');
my $length  = $lengths[0];
```

If you end up getting multiple `Content-length` headers and they're different then someone is very confused.

Comment: "someone is very confused" - Please don't anthropomorphise the web servers. They HATE it when you do that!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect this, at least not reliably. You could of course split the header value in the middle and try to find out if the left value is equal to the right but when you got sizes like 4444, you don't know if it's duplicated or not. The only chance to fix this is fixing it in the upstream server that sends you duplicated headers.

You could maybe try to access the content length via the content_length property:

```
$response->content_length
```

Maybe this is aware of duplicate headers, but i did not try it.